# Is there anyone encounter error running npm run build locally?

Tags: angular, npm, build, local

After installing all the dependencies using `npm install`, no errors encountered, I proceed to run `npm run build:prod:webinars` locally and this is what I got.

```
npm run build:prod:webinars

> webinar-ninja@6.0.0 build:prod:webinars /home/ushane/work/webinarninja/webinar-ninja/resources/angular
> nx build webinars --deploy-url /dist/webinars/ --configuration=production


> nx run webinars:build:production --deploy-url /dist/webinars/

Option "deployUrl" is deprecated: Use "baseHref" option, "APP_BASE_HREF" DI token or a combination of both instead. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url.
⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...Processing legacy "View Engine" libraries:
- angular-ga [es2015/esm2015] (git+https://github.com/SamVerschueren/angular-ga.git)
Encourage the library authors to publish an Ivy distribution.
⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
 —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 >  NX   Ran target build for project webinars (5m)
 
         With additional flags:
           --deploy-url=/dist/webinars/
 
    ✖    1/1 failed
    ✔    0/1 succeeded [0 read from cache]
 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webinar-ninja@6.0.0 build:prod:webinars: `nx build webinars --deploy-url /dist/webinars/ --configuration=production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webinar-ninja@6.0.0 build:prod:webinars script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ushane/.npm/_logs/2023-08-04T11_20_04_598Z-debug.log
```

I tried deleting the package-lock.json file and node_modules folder and clear cache by `npm cache clean --force` and then run `npm install` again, but no luck on. Error still occurs.

Comment: Which version of Angular is this ?

Comment: it's version 15.1.2